# In JS what is the most performant way to quickly store XY coordinate integers

Tags: javascript

I have recently learned after reading up on JS [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jscript/archive/2008/03/25/performance-optimization-of-arrays-part-i.aspx) that array's in JS are actually "sparse arrays" and are essentially an array of pointers and space is not allocated until needed. I know in C you can specify an array's type and allocate the needed space doing something such as int C[20];.

Right now I have a canvas paint application that records offsetX,offsetY and other data when an event occurs along with how many MS has elapsed when the event occurred. Of the many options of how to store this information from creating a Linked List of objects, to an array of objects, to even multiple arrays recording the integer values of each event.

After some research I have found that there are 3 ways of initializing and creating an array:

```
var arrayT = new Array(24);
var arrayW = [];
arrayW.length = 24;
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(24);
```

Although I have researched a bit into each of them, I am not exactly sure which would be optimal for efficient assignment of integers in a way that space is already pre allocated so that the JS engine does not need to constantly check an inputs data type and create space needed.Also if you think Arrays are not the best solution, what could I do to leverage the strengths of JS?

Comment: And how many millions of events are you expecting to occur per second? I'm guessing there is no reason here to worry about performance. Just allocate the array with e.g. `var events = [];` and then each time an event occurs you can do `events.push({x: xOffset, y: yOffset});`

Comment: You cannot pre-allocate the space, browser does not know what you will store inside the array. You would just have 24 undefined elements. Try to optimize your code logic, you cannot optimize this storing of integers. Just use `var buffer = []`.

Comment: hi SpiderPig: About 4000 events persecond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, standard JavaScript "arrays" [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html).

It's unlikely to actually matter except in rare extremely-performance-sensitive situations, but if you want a true pre-allocated array of integers, on any vaguely modern browser you can use `Int32Array` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int32Array), [spec](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-typedarray-constructors)):

```
var a = new Int32Array(24);
```

(Or `Int8Array` or `Int16Array`.)

Answer (score 0):

If it is from the array prototype they are all the same.
See for instance https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array